# How to test Android/iOS push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

My API also provides Push Notifications for Android/iOS. However, I'm only providing the server-side and therefore don't have an Android or iOS client to check if my server really works.

Does anybody know of a dummy client I could use in order to test my server?

Comment: What is your API ? Phone gap ?

Comment: Which API are you talking about? Phone Gap is client-side but I don't have a client... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android, I suggest you create a test application. If you don't have an Android device to test on, you can run it on the emulator. Without an application to test against, it would be difficult to test all the possible error responses that can be returned by GCM to your server. It would also be difficult (if not impossible) to get valid Registration IDs to send notifications to.

For iOS it's more difficult, since Apple Push Notifications are not supported in the emulator. You'll need a real device and a test application. Since the APNS server normally doesn't return responses (unless the message is rejected), having a device to verify that the notifications actually arrive is even more important.

Comment: For iOS, is it even possible to publish a test app? Wouldn't Apple block this?

Comment: @Dunken You don't have to actually publish it. You can test it in development mode (with sandbox APNS) or in AdHoc mode (with production APNS).